# Forward search from input file using TeXNicCenter

Tags: viewers, texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I'm using TeXnicCenter 2 Beta 1 (on a Windows Vista machine) and I am trying to use the forward search.  It is configured with SumatraPDF so that when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to `View Output`, SumatraPDF comes to the front and highlights the section where my cursor lives.

However this only works correctly when I execute `View Output` from the main file; if I try to execute `View Output` from an input file in the project, I get an error saying Forward Search cannot execute, and Sumatra appears saying that there is an error loading the nonexistent `.pdf` file.

Is there any way to get forward search to work from included files using TeXnicCenter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I only had to go to `Project` -> `Create with active file as main file` when my main file was active, and everything now goes fine with SumatraPDF.

Otherwise, if you already have an opened project, from the same menu execute `Properties` and indicate your main file.

Comment: Thanks.  At first this didn't seem to work, but after I ran `Build Output` from the input file it now appears to work.

Comment: Not at all... :-)